# Order of group given by the presentation $\langle \{a\}\mid \{a^r,a^s\}\rangle $ where $r$ and $s$ are coprime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

I want to find the order of a group given by the presentation $\langle \{a\} \mid \{a^r,a^s\}\rangle $ where $r$ and $s$ are coprime. My reasoning is as follows: since $a^r=1$ and $a^s=1$, the order will have to divide both $r$ and $s$. Then since $(r,s)=1$ it has to be $1$, right? Is this correct?

A follow-up question: if we drop the $(r,s)=1$ condition, would the order be the greatest common divisor of $r$ and $s$?

Comment: Yes and yes. Well done! It follows from [Bézout's Identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes.

Let $d=(r,s)$. Then by Bézout's Identity there exist $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ such that

$$xr+ys=d.$$

Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
a^d&=a^{xr+ys}\\
&=(a^r)^x(a^s)^y\\
&=1^x1^y\\
&=1.
\end{align}$$

Also $d\mid r$ and $d\mid s$, so there exist $n,m\in\Bbb Z$ such that $r=dm, s=dn$.

Let $b=a^d$. Then by Tietze transformations,

$$\begin{align}
\langle a\mid a^r, a^s\rangle &\cong \langle a,b\mid a^r, a^s, b=a^d=1\rangle\\
&\cong \langle a,b\mid b^m, b^n, b=a^d=1\rangle\\
&\cong \langle a\mid 1^m,1^n, a^d=1\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a\mid a^d\rangle,
\end{align}$$

which is cyclic of order $d=(r,s)$.